# Can someone give some tips to recreate this ribbon

Tags: modeling, rendering

What would be a good way to recreate the frills on the end and the lines inside of it ?[image]

Comment: if you have a PNG image with transparency you don't have to model, use the transparency

Comment: Yes, I made a lot of things like this: Import images as planes, add some cuts and subdivision.

Comment: Please read [this meta](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this) *(What is the problem with posting an image (or link) and asking “How do I do this?”)*. What exactly have you tried that has not worked? Please [edit] your question and show what you have tried that isn't working for you.